# Making density map based on number of hospitals in statistical area using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-pro, density

I have the longitude and latitude of hospitals in Australia and I want to make a density plot (Symbology - graduated colours) to visualise the distribution of hospitals by a statistical area (defined by Australian Bureau of Stats).

I've downloaded the shapefile from Aus Bureau of Stats.

The hospital data looks like this and I import it as XY event data:

```
Hospital name,Street address,Suburb,Postcode,State,Local Hospital Network (LHN),Primary Health Network area (PHN),Website,Description,Sector,Beds,Latitude,Longitude
Abbotsford Private Hospital,61 Cambridge Street,West Leederville,6007,WA,,,www.abbotsfordhospital.com.au,,Private,<50,-31.940992,115.837344
Adelaide Clinic,33 Park Terrace,Gilberton,5081,SA,,,www.adelaideclinic.com.au/,,Private,50-99,-34.90658,138.613167
```

I can get the hospitals overlayed on the map but I cant work out how to get it to colour the statistical area based on the number of hospitals in this area.

[image: green dots are hospitals and black lines are statistical areas]